Insufficient slope vs Extending concentric vent past deck for Rinnai RE199iP Tankless WH?
I'm replacing an existing tankless WH with a non-condensing Rinnai RE199iP tankless WH and would like to use the Ubbink concentric vent Rinnai recommends. The water heater would be in an awkward place - roughly in the middle of the an exterior block wall. Behind the wall where the WH will be installed is a deck, open on 2 sides, with about 4ft of clearance over grade, so running the vent through the wall (the most direct option) would put it ~1ft under a deck / ~3ft above grade (this is how the current WH is power vented - no intake). Running the vent to the left or right through a joist bay will require approximately 15ft of pipe, and by the manufacturers directions requires a 1/4" per foot drop either toward the outside or toward the unit with a condensate drain. In either scenario that requires approximately a 3 3/4" drop which won't be possible due to the width of my rim joist (2x8) - the best I could do would be ~1 1/2". Although that isn't to manufacturer spec, has anyone experienced issues with such a small drop? My other option would be to run the vent through the wall behind the WH, then run another 15ft or so of the concentric vent pipe under the deck so the cone sticks out past the edge of the deck. I have been unable to find any information about limitations on running the concentric vent pipe on the exterior of the house. Any advice is highly appreciated!
Location: PA climate Zone 5
